# Javascript, cloning, function and changing id's and names, any Ideas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, clone

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>

        function disable()
        {
            document.getElementById("habits").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("habits2").disabled=true;

            document.getElementById("exact").disabled=false;
        }
        function enable()
        {
            document.getElementById("habits").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("habits2").disabled=false;

            document.getElementById("exact").disabled=true;
        }
        var counter =0;
        var i = 0;
        function duplicate() { 
            var original = document.getElementById('div');
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone

            i+=1;
            clone.id = "div" + i; // there can only be one element with an ID
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

            document.getElementById('div' + i).getElementsByTagName('select').name += '_clone' + i;
            counter+=1;
        }

    </script>
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
 <button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Add List</button><br><br>
        <form id ="form" name="search" method="post" action="test.php">
            <div id="div">
                <div id="d">
                    <select name ="select" >
                        ...options...
                    </select>
                </div>

                Value:<input type="text" id ="exact">

                From: <input type="text" id="habits">
                To: <input type="text" id="habits2">

                <br>
                <input type="button" name="answer" value="Range" onclick="enable()"  >
                <input type="button" name="answer" value="Exact" onclick="disable()" >
            </div>
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" name ="search" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

My issue here is that, when I clone the `div id=div`, all the buttons work for the original one, even the cloned buttons. Another thing is that, when I click the submit button to get the options from the `drop-down list(s)`, but after submission, only the last drop-list is counted (cloned), but I want the original only.

Here is my page after clicking submit:

```
<?php
$item = $_POST["select"];
echo $item;
?>
```

How can I solve this? That is, changing the `id`'s and names, and functions working with the cloned elements?

Comment: The point is, you cannot have two elements with the same `id`. And if you do, the DOM only returns the first element. Try use `form[name]` instead to access form elements.

Comment: how to use it? I learnt this language two days ago, so I have no clue how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use id's if you want to duplicate things. Use and select by class (I strongly recommend to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)), and use `name="some_name[]"`

To solve your problem you can do: `onclick="javascript:enable(this)"` or, if you decide to use jQuery, use `onclick="javascript:jQuery(this)", and then you search for siblings of the current element (don't know the pure js syntax, just the jquery one, if you need help with jquery let me know).

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I have no background in jQuery, although most posts on here use jQuery to solve this. and what about enable(this)..what is the value of "this"?

Comment: `this` will be the parent - in this case the element on which you added the `onclick` to. e.g. `<div onclick="alert(this);"></div>` will alert the actual div element itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. i have changed the function by adding a line

```
   function duplicate() { 
                var original = document.getElementById('div');
                var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone

                i+=1;
               clone.attr("id",replace(clone.attr("id"),"div"+i));// change the id of clone div
              //  clone.id = "div" + i; // there can only be one element with an ID
                original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

                document.getElementById('div' + i).getElementsByTagName('select').name += '_clone' + i;
                counter+=1;
            }
```